# an SMS manager in android, the send result

Tags: android, sms, android-pendingintent

for SMS manager, the API is:
    sendTextMessage(phonenum, null,text, **null**,**null**).
I am confuse about the last two parameters. Who can show me the sample code about the last two parameters.
If I don't use the last two parameters, the SMS send is ok or not, how can I get it.

Answer (score 0):

[You can read more about SmsManager.The meaning of every parameter is described.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html)

Comment: I am confuse about the result from sms, should i have the intent to receive the result.How can i get the result not in the new activity, only in the background task?

Comment: i did not get, will you please explain about your requirement, about which result you are talking about.Please elaborate your question ..

Comment: the result about the SMS send, is OK or not?